# Duplicate validation in custom validation rule

Tags: yii

In model rules i have custom rule:

```
array('source_id, postcode, state, fname, lname, email, address, city, birthday, gender, ip, phone,validation', 'validateCustom', 'on'=>'spam,normal'),
```

The problem is, that this rule executes 12 times (number of attributes -1).

```
  public function validateCustom()
        {
//here all validations done
        }
```

How to prevent it? I want to validate all this params 1 time and not x. Thank you for any help.

Comment: The rule is executing once for each attribute (it validates each attribute separately). This is expected behavior. If you implement one of the attributes with a getter instead of a property you will see that the getter is not called 12 times.

Comment: If the validations are related, you should attach them to a single attribute only. If they are independent, you should reorganize your logic so that each call to validation only validates the target attribute without checking the others.

Comment: Actually its independent. Will try to atach to 1 attribute. here is gist if wanna more bad code)) https://gist.github.com/ineersa/6062995

Comment: Attaching to 1 attribute doesnt help.

Comment: @ineersa: You are using the validation rule completely wrong, I don't know where to begin. :/

Comment: well, its already on live system. the last problem left with this x duplicates on this rule. Its solved now with hack, but i need an answer))

Comment: How did you determine that "attaching to 1 attribute doesn't help"? If you assign this rule to only one attribute (e.g. `array('source_id', 'validateCustom')`), it will be called only once.

Comment: in this case, it will run once but wont pass other parameters then source_id. I lost 2 hrs yesterday fixing 15 min downtime after implementing this variant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an idea:

```
class YourModel extends ActiveRecord
{

   public $ranValidate = false;
   .......

    public function validateCustom($attribute, $params)
    {
        if($this->ranValidate == false) {
           //Implement your code
           $this->ranValidate = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I did something like this but easier. Thanks anyway.